# Mailgun not working in React throws error as soon as imported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mailgun

I want to use mailgun-js npm library in react but as soon as I import it in project it throws this error :

These dependencies were not found:

- dgram in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js, ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js and 1 other
- fs in ./node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js, ./node_modules/get-uri/file.js and 2 others

I have installed all these dependencies and I have also tried to isolate mailgun code in different nodejs file and then import its send function but still it throws the same error.